# How to concatenate a date and a time string and compare with a DateTime using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two strings, one of them for time only and the other for the date. I compare the concatenation with a DateTime.

I want to translate this SQl query to LINQ:

```sql
select count(*) from ViewAllTranUser
where TypeForm=15 
and DateCreate +' '+ TimeCreate<='2022/11/06 02:49:51'
and NameButton=2)>0
```

With:

```
DateCreate:2021/01/15
TimeCreate:02:38:57
```

I want to get the count of rows where DateTime is less than the concatenation of a given date and time.

Comment: Something like this : ViewAllTranUser.Where(x =>  x.TypeForm == 15 && DateTime.Parse(x.DateCreate + " " + x.TimeCreate) <= DateTime.Parse("2022/11/06 02:49:51") && x.NameButton ==2 && x.Count > 0)

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? And why don't you just compare both fields separately?

Comment: the problem of translate query to LINQ ,how can I Compare both fields separately when I receive the Date composite of Date and Time And Have Two Field in database defined as String

Comment: What about splitting the recevied string and then do `DateCreate < '2022/11/06' OR (DateCreate = '2022/11/06' AND TimeCreate <= '02:49:51')`.

Comment: That said, I'd strongly recommend to blend both database fields into one proper DateTime field `CreateDateTime`. It's a refactoring that will pay off big time.

Comment: Thanks For our the dateTime is should be in one Field but we work in the old database in project but i found the solution and make it as anwser you can see it

Answer (score 0):

the Problem was  receive date and Time and in database the date and time not in the same Field so I found the Solution by make the received as Text such as that
can replace the date - by / such as

```
var dateRelaced = actualQuantityManualDTO.DateGr.Replace("-", "/");
```

after that make text to collect the date and time
not every one of them is seperated by making map

CreateMap<ViewAllTranUser, ViewAllTranUserDTO>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.DateandTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src.DateCreate + ' ' + src.TimeCreate)));

and in the List Because The date be in arabic So I Make replace another for every item in list

var viewTransferList = _mapper.Map<List>(viewQuery);

```
    foreach (var date in viewTransferList) {
        date.DateandTime = date.DateandTime.Replace("ص", "AM");
        date.DateandTime = date.DateandTime.Replace("م", "PM");
    }
```

after that To make Comparison ca't make it in string type so I translate it

```
var MapperList = viewTransferList.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DateandTime) <= DateTime.Parse(dateRelaced)).ToList();
```

at end Is successed

Comment: This doesn't translate into SQL though.